# scroll to the top jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to create a simple "scroll jump to target". i have made the parts which it jumps to everywhere except the "scroll to top". the jump works on id of the tag so it jumps to everywhere fine but since i have my nav bar position fixed, it wont jump to the top. here is my code to make it simpler to understand:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a id="home" href="#home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

further down:

```
<div id="wall_1" class="myImage" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4" ></div>
    <div id="content_1" class="myContent">
        <div id="services"></div>
        ...
        <p><a href="#Home">Go to the top</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="wall_2" class="myImage" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4"  ></div>
    <div id="content_2" class="myContent" >
        <div id="about"></div>
        ...
        <p><a href="#Home">Go to the top</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="wall_3" class="myImage" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4"  ></div>
    <div id="content_2" class="myContent">
        <div id="contacts"></div>
        ...
        <p><a href="#Home">Go to the top</a></p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 81
            }, 800, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
               });
        });
    });
</script>
```

how can i jump to the top (scroll to 0) now?

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,0)` should do the trick or add the class `TopScroll` both to event selector `'a:not(.TopScroll)[href^="#"]'` and all the `a` tags

Comment: Why use jQuery?  Why not a simple anchor that doesn't require anything?  Or better yet, just let folks use their own scroll bar if they want to go to the top?

Comment: @ErsinBasaran : i tried `$('a[href="#Home"]').on('click', function (e) { window.scrollTo(0,0); });` but it doesnt work!!

Comment: @Ali Keep this code and change the selector in the original handler to `a:not([href="#Home"])[href^="#"]` so that it won't run

Comment: @ErsinBasaran okay, its a bit confusing for me since i'm a beginner. change the original handler? can your write the code please?

Comment: @Ali I mean the selector in click event handler in your question. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8f3tfvyr/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': 0
                }, 800, 'swing');
```

Comment: but that isnt link to any anchor tag! i tried this `$('a[href^="#Home"]').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 }, 800, 'swing');` and it didnt work as well!

Comment: Why does it need to be to an anchor tag?  So you can click it?  You can put that code in a function and call it using the anchor tag. `<a href="#" onclick="myScrollToTop();"</a>`